# Duplicate a folder tree over a network in C#

Tags: c#, file-structure

I have been tasked in creating a method that would replicate a full directory tree to a remote server using C#. The problem there is that I can **only** create the folder or the file if it has a **parent**.
I've decided to first get all folders along with their parents and store them in a tuple since a dictionary does not allow duplicates and the same thing was done to the files and then create the folders then the files.

```
public static void SubmitRecordToServer(string path) {

    IEnumerable < (string, string) > GetAllFolders(string root) {
        IEnumerable < string > folderslist = Directory.GetDirectories(root, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        IEnumerable < string > foldersnames = folderslist.Select(d = >new DirectoryInfo(d).Name).ToList();
        IEnumerable < string > foldersparents = folderslist.Select(d = >System.IO.Directory.GetParent(d).FullName).Select(path = >path.Replace(System.IO.Directory.GetParent(root).FullName, "")).ToList();
        IEnumerable < (string, string) > folderMapping = foldersnames.Zip(foldersparents, (x, y) = >(x, y.Substring(1)));
        return folderMapping;
    }

    IEnumerable < (string, string) > GetAllFiles(string root) {
        IEnumerable < string > files = Directory.GetFiles(root, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        IEnumerable < string > filenames = files.Select(Path.GetFileName);
        IEnumerable < string > parentfolders = files.Select(d = >System.IO.Directory.GetParent(d).FullName).Select(path = >path.Replace(System.IO.Directory.GetParent(root).FullName, "")).ToList();
        IEnumerable < (string, string) > filesMapping = filenames.Zip(parentfolders, (x, y) = >(x, y.Substring(1)));
        return filesMapping;
    }

    try {
        IEnumerable < (string, string) > directoryLevels = GetAllFolders(path);
        IEnumerable < (string, string) > filesLevels = GetAllFiles(path);

        foreach(var tuple in directoryLevels)
        CopyDirectory(tuple);

        foreach(var tuple in filesLevels)
        CopyFile(tuple);

    } catch(Exception ex) {
        throw ex;
    } finally {
             //Some handling
    }
```

I've omitted the *CopyDirectory* and *CopyFile* methods since they were provided to use as-is. The code is considered inefficient, how can I optimize it?

Comment: Why the weird spacing issues: `IEnumerable < string >`, `d = >new`?

Comment: @BCdotWEB I used an online code beautifier.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the Enumerable methods instead of the array ones.
`Directory.EnumerateDirectories` over `Directory.GetDirectories` and `Directory.EnumerateFiles` over `Directory.GetFiles`.  That way we don't store the entire tree structure in memory and also code doesn't wait for entire directory before moving forward.

Also making new DirectoryInfo just to get name is overkill.  As well as dumping everything into List.  Can mess with the directory structure just using it as strings.

```
IEnumerable<(string, string)> GetAllFolders(string root)
{
    var rootPath = Path.GetFullPath(root);
    return Directory.EnumerateDirectories(rootPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .Select(x => (Path.GetFileName(x),
            Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(x, @"..\")).Substring(rootPath.Length)));
}
```

Store the fullpath of the root outside the loop to just have it done once.  Then Path.GetFileName isn't smart enough to know it's a directory and will just return the directory name.  I know it's a bit confusing but a code comment would help anyone coming after that was looking at it.  To get the parent can add ..\ which will tell it to move back one directory and then get the fullpath to format it well.  Then just remove the root path length.

Could do similar optimizations on GetAllFiles.

Answer (score 2):

Here are my observations:

#### The `catch` block

This pattern what you have applied here (`throw ex;`) should be avoided. It re-throws the captured exception which alters the StackTrace. The origin of the exception will point to here, not where the original exception was thrown.

- Either simply use [`throw;` (without `ex`)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/throw#re-throwing-an-exception) if you want to perform some action (like logging) inside the `catch` block
- Or remove the `catch` block entirely. In C# a [`try`-`finally`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-finally) block without `catch` is also valid

#### `ValueTuple`

Both of your `GetAllFolders` and `GetAllFiles` methods return a collection of `string`, `string` tuple. From a caller perspective it is impossible to tell whether the left hand side of the tuple is the parent or the child.

Even though they are defined as local methods, their result are passed to non-local methods (`CopyDirectory`, `CopyFile`).

- Either use [named tuples](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples#tuple-field-names): `IEnumerable<(string Child, string Parent)>`
- Or define data structure via `struct` or [`record` or `record struct`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record): `record struct Paths(string Child, string Parent);`

#### Naming

##### The `CopyDirectory`, `CopyFile` methods

According to my understanding these method do not copy any data rather creates a folder or file. So, it might make more sense to call them  `CreateDirectory` and `CreateFile` to avoid misleading.

##### `folderslist`, `parentfolders`

Please prefer camelCasing for C# variables, like: `foldersList`, `parentFolders`, etc.

##### `x`, `y` and `d`

I would encourage you to use more descriptive names than a single letter it highly improves the legibility of your code, like

```
IEnumerable<(string Child, string Parent)> GetAllFiles(string root)
{
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(root, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    var parentFolders = files
        .Select(file => Directory.GetParent(file).FullName)
        .Select(path => path.Replace(Directory.GetParent(root).FullName, "").Substring(1));
    return files.Select(Path.GetFileName)
        .Zip(parentFolders, (file, folder) => (file, folder));
}
```

By the way in case of the `parentFolders` you don't need to call the `ToList` .

---

Last but not least I would like to emphasize how the [`Zip` method works](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-zip-3(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-1))-system-func((-0-1-2)))). If you have two collections with different size (lhs 3, rhs 4) then the produced output's length will be the length of the lhs (if its length is less or equal to rhs otherwise rhs's length). It may or may not be the desired behaviour in your case.